# Error al configurar una conexión a MySql con fluent nhibernate en .net core

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, nhibernate

Estoy programando la conexion a la base de datos para una api en net core
me decante por nhibernate pero no logro conectarme a la base de datos mysql, es una configuracion local lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

ese es mi CreateSessionFactory

```
 private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {


            string connection = "server='localhost';Database='equalsbd';UserId='root';Password='123456';port=3304";

            var db = MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connection);

            return Fluently.Configure().Database(db)
                         .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf
                          <SessionNHibernate>()).BuildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Esta es mi clase completa:

```
public class SessionNHibernate
{

    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    private static ISession session = null;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (sessionFactory == null)

                sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

            return sessionFactory;

        }

    }

    public static ISession Session
    {
        get { return session; }
    }
    public static ISession OpenSession() {
        try
        {
            session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
            return session;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var p = ex;
            return session;
        }
    }

    public static void CloseSession()
    {
        session.Close();
    }
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {


            string connection = "server='localhost';Database='equalsbd';UserId='root';Password='123456';port=3304";

            var db = MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connection);

            return Fluently.Configure().Database(db)
                         .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf
                          <SessionNHibernate>()).BuildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Edit: ya corregi el por que se detenia la ejecución parametrize mal la configuracion pero ahora me da este error

An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0):

PARA EVITAR ESE ERROR LO QUE DEBEN HACER ES CAMBIAR LAS PROPIEDADES DE SU ENTIDAD EN MI CASO LOS TENIA DE ESTA MANERA

```
public class Usuarios 
{
    public virtual long idUsuarios { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Usuario { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Perfiles_idPerfiles { get; private set; }

   public static List<Usuarios> ListaUsuario() {

        using (var session = SessionNHibernate.OpenSession() )
        {
            return session.Query<Usuarios>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

debe estar de esta manera

```
public class Usuarios 
{
    public virtual long idUsuarios { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Usuario { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Perfiles_idPerfiles { get; protected set; }

   public static List<Usuarios> ListaUsuario() {

        using (var session = SessionNHibernate.OpenSession() )
        {
            return session.Query<Usuarios>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```